# non-english file name into android phone using adb push

Tags: android

I am trying to push non-english file name into the phone(android 2.3.3), but get the follwing error.

**adb push test_folder /sdcard**

**failed to copy 'source' into 'dest' : Invalid argument.**

**cmd /U**, which enables unicode, didn't work. and the cmd window shows the name correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Odd, this seems to be working for me from a linux host.  If you open an interactive adb shell and cd to the scdcard, can you use 'touch' or 'cat' to create a file with the desired name?  If so you might be able to push your file under some other name and then re-name ('mv') it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a [known/open issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8185).